# If you attended TASTI 2023, which talks might you find particularly interesting/informative?

Tags: discussion

[TASTI 2023](https://tasti2023.com/) (Taiwan International Assembly of Space Science, Technology, and Industry) runs all next week in Taipei. There will be many talks - some days have several parallel sessions. ([keynote speakers](https://tasti2023.com/program/keynote-speakers)).

Because of the [Taiwan Space Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_Space_Agency) (formerly NPSO)'s big footprint in the GNSS signal occultation measurement of atmospheric water vapor for weather prediction via the FORMOSAT program and now with the successful launch of [TRITON/FORMOSAT 7R](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/formosat-7r.htm) many of the talks by both US' NOAA and Taiwan's space agency and meteorological community will somewhat dominate the conference. However there will be presentations by several other space interests, including about the [Advance Rocket Research Center](https://arrc.tw/)'s upcoming hover tests and eventual launches.

I'm overwhelmed by all the choices, so I'd like to ask this meta question:

**Question:** If you attended TASTI 2023, which talks might you find particularly interesting/informative?

Comment: In Astronomy Meta there are not-the-same-but-somewhat-similar "soft questions" of this general class, so I think this may be sufficiently on-topic here. [What are your plans for the Annular Solar Eclipse on October 14th, 2023?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/932/7982) and [Post your pictures of the Beaver Moon Lunar Eclipse here!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/816/7982) and [Post your pictures of the Great Conjunction here!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/651/7982) (also posted in [Space Explor. SE](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3078/12102))

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment because I deleted my account when I was off and I still need 5 points.

I would be interested in Space Law and Policy. It would be interesting if they talk about UFO and the recent change in legislation that put NASA, not the military, in charge of the research.